# Display images in json file using jquery

Tags: jquery, json

I have a JSON file which includes 8 images, each image I would like to display with a class. I have tried to load the first image to the first class however it isn't working.

The jQuery I have tried:

```
  jQuery(function($) {
   $.getJSON('example.json', function (response) {
    $('.tile-image1').each(function(i) {
     $(this).append('<div><img src= "' + response.Tiles[i].img[i].img1 + '"> 
     </div>');
     });
    });
   });
```

HTML:

```
  <div class="tile-image1"></div>
  <div class="tile-image2"></div>
  <div class="tile-image3"></div>
  <div class="tile-image4"></div>
```

JSON:

```
 {
"Tiles" : [
  {
    "title" : "",
    "year" : "-",
    "category" : "",
    "img": {
    "img1" : "example.jpg",
    "img2" : "example.jpg",
    "img3" : "example.jpg",
    "img4" : "example.jpg"
    }
  },
  {
    "title" : "",
    "year" : " -",
    "category" : "",
    "img" : {
    "img1" : "example.jpg",
    "img2" : "example.jpg",
    "img3" : "example.jpg",
    "img4" : "example.jpg"
    }
   }
  ]
 }
```

So what I am trying to achieve is all of the "img1" in the JSON file to be displayed with the class tile-image1, all of the "img2" to the class tile-image2, etc. I am new to this and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: 1 you're using `i` for both outer and inner loop.  1st title+1st image then 2nd title+2nd image.  You would need an inner loo - but:  2. `img` is not an array so you can't use `img[i]`. Change `.img[i].img1` to `.img.img1`

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you need to loop through the arrays in the object itself not the elements in the DOM. That way you can populate the target `div` containers with the relevant `img` elements.

You will need two loops, one to go through `Tiles`, and another to go through the properties of the `img` object within each tile. Note that I amended the classes on the `div` to DRY this up a little.

```
$.getJSON('example.json', function (response) {
  response.Tiles.forEach(function(tile) {
    Object.keys(tile.img).forEach(function(imgKey) {
      $('.' + imgKey).append('<div><img src="' + tile.img[imgKey] + '">  </div>');
    });
  });
});
```

```js
var response = {
  "Tiles": [{
    "title": "",
    "year": "-",
    "category": "",
    "img": {
      "img1": "example_1_1.jpg",
      "img2": "example_1_2.jpg",
      "img3": "example_1_3.jpg",
      "img4": "example_1_4.jpg"
    }
  }, {
    "title": "",
    "year": " -",
    "category": "",
    "img": {
      "img1": "example_2_1.jpg",
      "img2": "example_2_2.jpg",
      "img3": "example_2_3.jpg",
      "img4": "example_2_4.jpg"
    }
  }]
}

jQuery(function($) {
  // inside AJAX callback...
  response.Tiles.forEach(function(tile) {
    Object.keys(tile.img).forEach(function(imgKey) {
      $('.' + imgKey).append('<div><img src="' + tile.img[imgKey] + '">  </div>');
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tile-image img1"></div>
<div class="tile-image img2"></div>
<div class="tile-image img3"></div>
<div class="tile-image img4"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I create a code-snippet, might inspires you to do the rest:

```js
var jsonData= {
"Tiles" : [
  {
    "title" : "",
    "year" : "-",
    "category" : "",
    "img": {
    "img1" : "example.jpg",    "img2" : "example.jpg",
    "img3" : "example.jpg",    "img4" : "example.jpg"
    }
  },  {
    "title" : "",
    "year" : " -",
    "category" : "",
    "img" : {
    "img1" : "example.jpg",    "img2" : "example.jpg",
    "img3" : "example.jpg",    "img4" : "example.jpg"
    }
   }
  ]
 };
 
 
   //jQuery(function($) {
 jsonData.Tiles.map(list=>{
     //console.log(list)
     Object.values(list.img).map((imgLink,i)=>{
     let index = i+1;
     $('.tile-image'+i).append('<div><img src="'+imgLink+'"></div>');

  })

 })
```

```css
div{
  width:25%;
  display:flex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="tile-image1"></div>
  <div class="tile-image2"></div>
  <div class="tile-image3"></div>
  <div class="tile-image4"></div>
```